# I want to enable right click on image only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am using code to block right click on my blog. It's work for may website and disable ctrl+v ctrl+c-right click f12 on my webpage. But I want to enable right click on image. I don't know how to do that.  But  Please Help me.

```
var isCtrl = false;
document.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.which == 17)
    isCtrl = false;
}

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.which == 123)
    isCtrl = true;

  if (((e.which == 85) || (e.which == 65) || (e.which == 88) || (e.which == 67) || (e.which == 86) || (e.which == 2) || (e.which == 3) || (e.which == 123) || (e.which == 83)) && isCtrl == true) {
    alert('This is Function Disabled');
    return false;
  }
}

// right click code
var isNS = (navigator.appName == "Netscape") ? 1 : 0;
if (navigator.appName == "Netscape")
  document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN || Event.MOUSEUP);

function mischandler() {
  alert('This is Function Disabled');
  return false;
}

function mousehandler(e) {
  var myevent = (isNS) ? e : event;
  var eventbutton = (isNS) ? myevent.which : myevent.button;
  if ((eventbutton == 2) || (eventbutton == 3)) return false;
}

document.oncontextmenu = mischandler;
document.onmousedown = mousehandler;
document.onmouseup = mousehandler;

//select content code disable  alok goyal
function killCopy(e) {
  return false
}

function reEnable() {
  return true
}

document.onselectstart = new Function("return false")
if (window.sidebar) {
  document.onmousedown = killCopy
  document.onclick = reEnable
}
```

Comment: You want to enable right click on an image of your blog? your question is too vague, can you be more precise!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy using `event.target` we can **enable/disable** right-click when mouse **enters/leaves** a particular image section on your web page.

Just see a demo of the same below

```js
var isCtrl = false;
document.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.which == 17)
    isCtrl = false;
}

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.which == 123)
    isCtrl = true;

  if (((e.which == 85) || (e.which == 65) || (e.which == 88) || 
  (e.which == 67) || (e.which == 86) || (e.which == 2) || 
  (e.which == 3) || (e.which == 123) || (e.which == 83)) && isCtrl == true) {
    alert('This is Function Disabled');
    return false;
  }
}

// right click code
var isNS = (navigator.appName == "Netscape") ? 1 : 0;
if (navigator.appName == "Netscape")
  document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN || Event.MOUSEUP);

function mischandler(e) {
  let target = $(e.target);
  if(!target.is('#img')) {
   alert('This is Function Disabled');
   return false;
  }
}

function mousehandler(e) {
  var myevent = (isNS) ? e : event;
  var eventbutton = (isNS) ? myevent.which : myevent.button;
  if ((eventbutton == 2) || (eventbutton == 3)) return false;
}

document.oncontextmenu = mischandler;
document.onmousedown = mousehandler;
document.onmouseup = mousehandler;

$('#img').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
 mischandler(e);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src='https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg' id='img' alt='mountain.jpg' width='200' height='200'/>
```

Hope, this works fine to you. :) :)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated code which checks if selected element is image. Using event object we can check the nature of selected element

```
function mischandler(e) { //change
    if(e.currentTarget.getAttribute("src")==null) //change
    {
        alert('This is Function Disabled');
        return false;
    }

}

function mousehandler(e) {
  var myevent = (isNS) ? e : event;
  var eventbutton = (isNS) ? myevent.which : myevent.button;
  if (((eventbutton == 2) || (eventbutton == 3)) && e.currentTarget.getAttribute("src")==null) //change
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45871372/1326147) amit, but your code is not what I was looking for. I am replying here because you deleted the answer. I added code into a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Armfoot/pen/NvBojY) based on your example to show you my point, i.e. the `:hover` color values of specific elements is what I need, even if they are not triggered by hovering. In this example, only the `p#blue` works because the event is triggered while hovering. Your example was doing the same...

Comment: @Armfoot   Now i got your query, Adding my answer again, Yes you can get those by reading stylesheets using document.stylesheet, Adding my answer with jsfidlle code.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery I think a rather simple solution would be:

```
 $(document).on( "contextmenu", function(event) {
//if image allow normal browser behaviou
        if(event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'img'){
            return true;
        }else{
//if any other event target prevent default
            event.preventDefault;
            alert("no right click");
            return false;
        }
    })
```

Comment: But ctrl+c f12 key are enable. Your code only turn off mouse right click. I want to disable ctrl+c f12 ctrl+u ctrl+shift+i and also mouse right click.