# How to access the focus/hover/visited CSS properties of an element through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I may be tired and thinking oddly right now, but I simply cannot find how to retrieve the values of CSS properties defined in an element's focused, hovered or visited states. The goal is to use the values in Javascript.

*Important*: I **do not need to get the focused/hovered/visited elements**. I want to access certain **values of any element** in the DOM with **CSS properties defined for the following states**: `:focus`, `:hover` and `:visited`.

These pseudo-classes do not seem to help in this case, so do I need to trigger the respective state in order to access the values?

It should be simpler than this... Or is it not?

P.S.: Answers in vegetarian Javascript or jQuery will do.

Comment: You'll likely have to parse the stylesheet itself to get these values. What are you ultimately trying to accomplish? There's probably a better approach to take.

Comment: Thanks @Blazemonger, I am afraid of going "through the monster" possibility... My goal is to get certain of those values into Javascript in order to reuse them in the same or other elements, a basic example is to invert the colors of the element's states after some event is triggered.

Comment: There might be other ways to do that. Either use a utility class which can be added or removed easily using JavaScript, or look up [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*)

Comment: "Answers in vegetarian Javascript or jQuery will do." What about vegan JavaScript? (Disclaimer: not actually vegan.)

Comment: @BoltClock Good question, my guess is that vegan JS would not use [`dairy.js`](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168169915003427).

Comment: Thanks again @Blazemonger, this really is a nice feature! It's almost like using SASS! Even though it's experimental, it seems to work pretty well! It also preserves the original values written in the CSS ([codepen example](https://codepen.io/Armfoot/pen/rzrPBQ)). I may give it a go!

Comment: [Here's a quick introduction to using CSS custom properties with JavaScript.](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/04/start-using-css-custom-properties/#using-custom-properties-with-javascript) Might solve your use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can achieve this by reading style sheets.
You can get it by using document.styleSheets;  Below is the example and jsfiddle link.

http://jsfiddle.net/wt3qQ/

> For **security reasons**, Opera and Mozilla will not allow you to access
>   the cssRules collection of a stylesheet from another domain or
>   protocol. Attempting to access it will throw a **security violation
>   error**

```
function getStyleBySelector( selector )
   {
       var sheetList = document.styleSheets;
       var ruleList;
       var i, j;

       /* look through stylesheets in reverse order that
          they appear in the document */
       for (i=sheetList.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
       {
           ruleList = sheetList[i].cssRules;
           for (j=0; j<ruleList.length; j++)
           {
               if (ruleList[j].type == CSSRule.STYLE_RULE && 
                   ruleList[j].selectorText == selector)
               {
                   return ruleList[j].style;
               }   
           }
       }
       return null;
   }

console.log(getStyleBySelector('a:hover').color);
console.log(getStyleBySelector('#link:hover').color);
```

Comment: This is indeed a nice attempt and it goes along with what Blazemonger was suggesting (parsing the stylesheet). I was expecting it to be more complex, though it still looks a bit heavy on performance. Thanks amit.